# Run multiple classes separately in netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans, server, client

I am writing a code for chatting between client server. I have 2 classes, one for server and one for client. Both containing main functions. I need a way to run the classes separately. first server class then client class. But when I am running the program, net beans run the entire project. How can i run both of these classes separately ??

Comment: Run each in new Instance of NetBeans!

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the Projects window, right click on the server java file and select "Run File". Then right click on the client java file and select "Run File".